# Youtube video navigation widget

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hyperlink, youtube

Hi Im trying to create a widget where the user can navigate a youtube video with buttons. For example if it's a video of a car race there would be 5 button each labeled Lap 1, Lap 2, and so on.

Im thinking of using an extension on the video url. If you at &t=1m22s och a video it loads from 1 minute and 22 seconds. Is there a way to use iframe and javascript to make this work?

Example link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKp9g8fTBDQ

Example with time link extension (Phone Start Up):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKp9g8fTBDQ&t=3m52s

I hope you understand what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const src = $("#video")[0].src;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#lap1').on('click', function(ev) {
    $("#video")[0].src = src + "&start=60";
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#lap2').on('click', function(ev) {
    $("#video")[0].src = src + "&start=200";
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#lap3').on('click', function(ev) {
    $("#video")[0].src = src + "&start=300";
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
.button {
  font: bold 20px Arial;
  background-color: #FF8000;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="lap1" class="button" href="#">Lap 1</a>
<a id="lap2" class="button" href="#">Lap 2</a>
<a id="lap3" class="button" href="#">Lap 3</a>
</br>
<iframe id="video" width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/J4LI_EqnJq8?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[Run the Code](https://jsfiddle.net/a0czz947/)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot and you are awesome!